# Can't install "react-native-tab-view-collapsible-header"

Tags: react-native, npm, tabs, header, react-navigation-collapsible

When i try run the command on my terminal (pointed to the correct directory): "npm i react-native-tab-view-collapsible-header"

I get errors saying:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: projectname
npm ERR! Found: react-native-head-tab-view@4.0.0-rc.13
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-head-tab-view
npm ERR!   react-native-head-tab-view@"^4.0.0-rc.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-head-tab-view@"^4.0.0" from react-native-tab-view-collapsible-header@2.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-tab-view-collapsible-header
npm ERR!   react-native-tab-view-collapsible-header@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

Here is my package.js:

"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
"expo": "~43.0.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-head-tab-view": "^4.0.0-rc.13",
"react-native-pager-view": "5.4.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-web": "0.17.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use yarn add instead of npm install